# Why does LaTeX include padding/margin on the left side of the document by default, and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: latex

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \lipsum
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \lipsum
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document looks like this:

[image: pdf output]

The whole document seems to be shifted to the right. There is spacing at the left edge, while at the same time the text is overflowing on the right side. Why is that?

My code is pretty simplistic, I do not see why this spacing should be there, and how I could get rid of it. Thanks in advance for any input on this!

Comment: Non-programming questions about LaTeX are best suited for [TeX & LaTeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between paragraphs, latex by default indents the first line of every new paragraph. You can switch this off either by using `\noindent` before the paragraph or globally by changing the `\parindent`.

Also note that your unprotected line endings will act like spaces and this your line with two `.5\textwidth` minipages is actually wider than the available text width.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```